# $_REQUEST cannot recived in other php file

Tags: php, html, session, request

im trying to send a $_REQUEST data from a.php to b.php php file.

but at b.php $_REQUEST always empty.

whats wrong in my code? i hope someone can help me to solve this error

is $_request is same with $_session?

this a.php

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $name=$_POST['txtName'];
    $location=$_POST['txtLocation'];
    $status=$_POST['txtStatus'];
    $description=$_POST['txtDescription'];
    $spesification=$_POST['txtSpesification'];
    $lokasi_file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $nama_file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $folder="images/qrcode/$nama_file";
    $folder2="images/qrcode/$nama_file";

    $query="INSERT INTO perangkat(name,location,status,description,spesification,qrcode) VALUES ('$name','$location','$status','$description','$spesification','$folder2')".mysql_error();
    $upload=move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,$folder);
    $hasil=mysql_query($query);
    if($hasil & $upload)
    {
        echo("<br>Input data berhasil!");
        $result= mysql_query("SELECT device_id FROM perangkat where name='$name'") or die (mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $qrcode=$row['device_id'];
        $_REQUEST['data'] = $qrcode;
        //echo $qrcode;
        header('location:b.php');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo("Maaf input data gagal");
    }
?>
```

this b.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) { 

    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.($_REQUEST['data']).'.png';
    QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);    

    } else {    

    //default data
    echo 'You can provide data in GET parameter: <a href="?data=like_that">like that</a><hr/>';    
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send data to other page by query string, session or using other method

**Using query string** :-

```
header('location:b.php?data='.$qrcode);
```

and get on b.php

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
```

**Using session** :-

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['data'] = $qrcode;
```

on getting b.php

```
session_start()
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is not the same as `$_SESSION`.

`$_REQUEST` is an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Don't forget, because `$_REQUEST` is a different variable than `$_GET` and `$_POST`, it is treated as such in PHP -- modifying `$_GET` or `$_POST` elements at runtime will not affect the elements in `$_REQUEST`, nor vice versa.

e.g:

```
<?php

$_GET['foo'] = 'a';
$_POST['bar'] = 'b';
var_dump($_GET); // Element 'foo' is string(1) "a"
var_dump($_POST); // Element 'bar' is string(1) "b"
var_dump($_REQUEST); // Does not contain elements 'foo' or 'bar'

?>
```

To use session you must start your php file with `session_start();`
Then you can use the session like: `$_SESSION['data'] = $qrcode;`